# I have a list of long integers that I assign to a django model charfield. The list of longs get converted to list of unicodes

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have a list of long integers that I assign to a django model Charfield. 
The list of longs get converted to list of unicodes.

```
other_parents = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

final_list = [1L, 2L, 11L, 84L]
self.parent_list = final_list
print self.parent_list
```

prints [u'1', u'2', u'11', u'84']

Can we keep it as list of longs.

Comment: Your question doesn't makes too much sense. If you want to store Long integers use `models.BigIntegerField`. Also if you want to store whole list of them, probably you should create separate table with foreign key. Last option would be to create custom field based on `TextField` which will parse list into comma separated string (or JSON) during save and split it (or decode JSON) on retrieve value.

If you need more help add more specific use case.

Comment: Hi daniula, Thanks for taking time to answer this. I agree with what you are saying. However I would like to know how to address this specific scenario.

Comment: @AbhisheshSharma post your complete relevant code. What is self here and what is parent_list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Django documentation: Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-model-fields/) I've created simple field `LongListAsTextField()` which extends default `django.db.models.TextField` and converts list of longs from and to string with `to_python` and `get_prep_value` methods.

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from django.db import models

from .fields import LongListAsTextField

class Record(models.Model):
    parent_list = LongListAsTextField()
```

**fields.py**

from django.db import models

from django.utils.six import with_metaclass

```
class LongListAsTextField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.TextField)):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
           return value

        return [
            long(val)
            for val in value.split(',')
            if val.isdigit()
        ]

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return ','.join([str(val) for val in value])
```

**shell**

```
Record(parent_list=[1,2]).save()
record = Record.objects.last()
record.parent_list # returns [1L, 2L]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive and to the point answer ! I also created a custom model field and overridden to_python and prepare_values methods and getting some issues I had to override get_prep_value it seems! Thanks a ton !

Comment: Custom fields are a little tricky with its methods. Also make sure you inherit from SubfieldBase.

Comment: I specified the meta class like 
    
    ____metaclass____ = models.SubfieldBase inside the class extended from TextField Class. Worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Django does handle serialisation and storage of your list of longs into your database `CharField` field without you doing anything. You don't need a custom field; `CharField` will convert the list using `bytes()`, convert that to UTF8, and store it in your database. Your list may contain strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None, or combinations thereof.

The problem you have is that when you retrieve the list from the database, it will be a unicode string, not a Python list. No problem, provided that you limit your data types to those mentioned above, you can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely unmarshall the list:

In **your_app/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class List(models.Model):
    the_list = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

Then in `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> from your_app.models import List

>>> original_list = [1, 2, 3, 444L, 1100L, -1234, 11.72, 'hi there', u'\u3030\u3000', {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1, 2, 3]}, ('this', 'is', 'a', 'tuple'), True, None]
>>> List(the_list=original_list).save()
>>> retrieved_list = List.objects.last()
>>> retrieved_list
u"[1, 2, 3, 444L, 1100L, -1234, 11.72, 'hi there', u'\\u3030\\u3000', {'a': 1, 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 2}, ('this', 'is', 'a', 'tuple'), True, None]"
>>> original_list == ast.literal_eval(retrieved_list.the_list)
True
```

Which shows that the list was successfully round-tripped through the database.

Comment: Thanks for sparing time to answer this ! I'll check this and get back !